# Wix: Cannot upgrade from 'single user' installation to 'all user' installation

Tags: windows, installation, wix, upgrade, uninstallation

My WIX script upgraded older installations correct until I changed it to an all-user installation.
Now an upgrade results in 2 items in the Windows add/remove programs list.

With the older versions, the shortcuts were added to:
C:\Users\xxx1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\xxx2.
This was not correct.

After I added  to the Wix script, the shortcuts were added to:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\xxx2.
This is correct. But now an upgrade is not working anymore (double entries in Windows Add/remove).

I tried several thinks like:

- Setting the “ALLUSERS” flag after uninstall. No success.
- Manually trying to deinstall the previous version. Could not get it working
- Forcing administrator Privileges by using: InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes" InstallScope="perMachine". No success.

Question: How can I upgrade correct (or deinstall before installation) after I changed my Wix script from 'single user' to 'all user'?

Answer (score 0):

correct. That's a Windows Installer limitation.

Even if MSI could do this, it couldn't reach out to the X number of other users on the machine that might need to have their per-user removed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades

> If an application is installed in the per-user installation context,
> any major upgrade to the application must also be performed using the
> per-user context. If an application is installed in the per-machine
> installation context, any major upgrade to the application must also
> be performed using the per-machine context. The Windows Installer will
> not install major upgrades across installation context.